# Eclipse Deployment Assembly does not appear in properties

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In a new project of mine I cannot see the Deployment Assembly link in the project properties.
It is There in my other projects which are configured in the same way (as far as I can see).

I have dynamic web module and java in the facets. I have m2eclipse installed and invoked the menu option "update project configuration". I am running eclipse 3.7 EE edition. I have google eclipse plugin also.

What I want to know is how to get the deployment assembly option to appear so I can configure which resources are pushed out to local server through WTP.

My .project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>shortbread</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to add `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>` to your .project file. The Plugin Spy (ALT+SHIFT+F1) is very helpful to find out stuff like that. The Property Page is defined in the plugin `org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui` and in the plugin.xml file you can see, that the DeploymentAssemblyPage is `enabledWhen` the `projectNature` is `org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature`.

Comment: Didn't fix for my GAE sample.  Deployment Assembly option appeared displayed "Error Checking Project Facets" when selected.

Comment: Wouldn't have found this in a hundred years.

Comment: And this is exactly why I hate eclipse, how could a user ever imagine that??? Thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome. But "hate" is such a strong word ;-) I've been working with Visual Studio the last few months... And regarding the "user" - that, at least in this case, is a developer, so...

Comment: To paraphrase [ihateeclipse.com](http://www.ihateeclipse.com): "Hate is a very strong word. It's not nearly strong enough for most people when talking about Eclipse, though." :D
Ok, I'm clearly joking here but I still believe even a developer is not supposed to understand eclipse internals to have it working properly..

Comment: Added the <nature>, still no Deployment option. Agree with oidualc, Eclipse is unintuitive and inconsistent with every other IDE out there. I have more important things to do than learn "the Eclipse way".

Comment: Alt-Shift-F1 doesn't do anything

Comment: Well, looks like some things have changed in eclipse in the last ~10 years..

Answer (score 19):

When I tried to add this config to the .project, I had the same problem that wharron, **"Error Checking Project Facets"**, then I went to the "**Project Facets**" option of the build path , I choose a custom one, then checked the option "**Utility Module**", Applied and the next time I opened the build path the Deployment Assembly was there and working ok.

Comment: Thanks @Alejandra. This worked for me with Eclipse Luna 4.4.0.

Comment: Thanks Alejandra, it helped me!

Answer (score 8):

I also face the same problem and I follow the below steps and my problem was resolved.i have checked my dynamic web module in the second screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the accepted answer add `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>` to .project file and also add `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>` to resolve "Error Checking Project Facets" in Deployment Assembly screen.

**If importing existing project Keep "existing project descriptors" do not Overwrite as eclipse will remove these natures from .project file in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Solved this with two simple steps

1. `right click on the project > Build path > configure build path > Project facets` then make sure you have the `Dynamic Web Module` checked
2. right click on the project > run as >  run on server

then you could see the error is gone by going  back to

`Build path > configure build path > Deployment ssembly`