# Edit .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I have cloned a new project from the old one using Eclipse Java EE IDE (Helios SR2). 
After renaming context, components, folders, file name etc... I still have the following file **`.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`** keeping the old project name: **OLDPROJECT**

```
<wb-module deploy-name="OLDPROJECT">
```

and

```
<property name="java-output-path" value="/OLDPROJECT/build/classes"/>
```

I tried to look for it in Project -> Properties but failed. So, could you please tell me how I can edit the file using Eclipse IDE?

**`.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`**

```
    <wb-module deploy-name="OLDPROJECT">

        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>

        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>

        <property name="java-output-path" value="/OLDPROJECT/build/classes"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="NEWPROJECT"/>
    </wb-module>

</project-modules>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890409

Right-clicking on an EAR project > Properties > Deployment Assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The file is edited with the properties dialog "Deployment assembly": https://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php

If the dialog does not show up in project properties add org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature
to your .project file:

[Eclipse Deployment Assembly does not appear in properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399885/eclipse-deployment-assembly-does-not-appear-in-properties)

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like there is a way to edit this attribute from project properties. It does update correctly when you rename the project. You will need to update the configuration file directly.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin Komissarchik

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-H, File search tab, enter 'deploy-name' in `containing text` field. Hit enter.

Then `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` will be a result. Double-click and edit it.