# what is org.eclipse.wst.common.component and how to use it for ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jboss

I have an eclipse workspace (for work) that has an ear project that I use to "export"/deploy an ear file to a JBoss server.

However, they recently asked me to create an ant script that can build the workspace and create the ear, and I have done this successfully. The problem arises when I try to run my program with this ear that was built using the ant script; for deploying I'm simply copying the resulting ear file and pasting it into the JBoss/standalone/deployments folder and running the application.

The JBoss AS starts fine, but then I get a few exceptions that halt my application that I do not get when I do a build and deploy through eclipse. The two ear files are identical when viewing the two ear files using 7zip, however I see in the eclipse workspace, in the ear project, theres a .settings folder that has 4 files, one of them being org.eclipse.wst.common.component and I'm guessing this (if not all 4 files) is necessary when deploying somehow.

Does ecplise use this .settings folder and the files inside when deploying an ear? What happens during this process? and how can I replicate it in an ant script so that my application runs identically from either ant or eclipse builds?

***EDIT***

let me just add that none of the files in the .settings folder get packaged up in the ear file, so I'm guessing they're somehow used when eclipse does a build/deploy, but it doesnt get placed in the final ear product

thank you

Comment: The .settings folder in a project stores preferences for various plugins (always called plugin-id.prefs)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eclipse uses the data in `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` to figure out the dependencies needed for deployment. The file corresponds to the settings found in Eclipse when `Right-clicking on an EAR project > Properties > Deployment Assembly`.

E.g. if your EAR project has a dependency on a WAR project then Eclipse knows to include the WAR when deploying because of the *Deployment Assembly* settings which get stored in `org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

When building the EAR using Ant you need to add these dependencies manually (without relying on Eclipse metadata)

Comment: thank you for the answer, how can I add dependencies manually? using apache Ivy?

Comment: You don't **need** Ivy. You could probably use the [EAR task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html) and make sure that all the needed JARs and WARs are included in the EAR archive.
For more advanced dependency management you could use Ant+Ivy but in general my personal recommendation would be to rather to use something like Gradle.