# What is the purpose of org.eclipse.wst.common.component ? Is this a auto generated file which contains dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I have updated my build.gradle file and removed few unnecessary dependencies and performed gradle refresh, the unnecessary dependencies still exist in the org.eclipse.wst.common.component file. I am not sure if I should manually remove the dependency from org.eclipse.wst.common.component file present under .setting in my spring boot project

Comment: The `.settings` folder in an Eclipse project contains internal Eclipse settings (for things like preferences and other project specific settings). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24828453/2670892)