# How to find the plugin which defined a specific class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

In the answer of [Eclipse Deployment Assembly does not appear in properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399885/eclipse-deployment-assembly-does-not-appear-in-properties), @CodeSeavers mentioned about: "**The Property Page is defined in the plugin org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui "**. 
But how did @CodeSeavers do to know that? Please show me step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question, but this is what I usually do:

1. Use the plugin spy (Alt + Shift + F1) on any view, editor or anything for that matter to get complete info about that. Primarily used for plugin developers to find the ID, and stuff. In this case it's used to get the name of the plugin that contributes the property page.
2. Use the Plugin Search - (Ctrl + H). And search for any Extension point or the plugin. From the search result you can look into the plugin.xml and figure what the plugin contributes and how it is used.
3. Or you can always directly view the source code and check things out. Almost all the plugins that comes with eclipse has a source build to it. That makes life easier.