# Deployment Assemply is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I got one weird problem with eclipse as well as in Spring Tool Suite.

At first I created a Maven project in Eclipse, And it works absolutely fine without an issue. As in below image you can see "**Deployment Assembly**" option is visible in it.

[image]

So, after that I copied the entire project as it is and given to my friend. So he imported it as maven project, But the option of "Deployment Assembly" was not visible, due to which "Tomcat's **LifeCycleException**" occurs. We can solve that solve that exception only when we add Maven dependencies at java build path entries, But for that you need Deployment Assembly option to be visible.

Here is the screenshot taken from my friend's Eclipse after importing my project as it is without any change.
[image]

So is anyone know the cause of this. As I am getting that exception. Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399885/eclipse-deployment-assembly-does-not-appear-in-properties

Comment: @soorapadman Thanks, tried using it, Deployment Assembly is visible now, But got an error when I click on Deployment Assembly "currently displayed page contains invaliud values"